# SpriteKit Mirror Physics/Math?

Tags: sprite-kit, trigonometry, mirror, light

So I'm making a game with a bunch of mirrors in it and a little beam of light is gonna hit them and reflect into the other mirrors. However, I'm only in Algebra I and have done very little trig (and by that I mean I kinda sorta know what sin and cos are). So math wise, how can I have a little beam dude hit a mirror that is rotated to a certain angle, at a certain angle, and turn around to the correct angle and go about its happy little light beam life? I have the beam moving in the direction it's facing like this:

```
class LightBeam: SKSpriteNode {
func update() {
    let dx = 5 * cos(self.zRotation)
    let dy = 5 * sin(self.zRotation)
    print(dx);print(dy)
    self.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(dx, y: dy, duration: 0.2))
    ...
```

Sorry if this is unclear. Any help would be scrumptious. Thanks!